# Use of tildes and ñ python SVN

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that searches for some documents in a repository without using a client, but when it returns the URLs (I need that), it prints the `ó` like this: `m?\\195?\\179viles`. I put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` but nothing happens. How can I fix this?

I use Python3, Python2 and CentOS.

Comment: I changed my locale to es_ES in centOS, and str.encode("iso-8859-15") or encode("utf-8"), but now only appears "?" for example: m?viles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal isn't supporting utf-8. You can check it with:

```
echo $LC_CTYPE
```

Try changing it with:

```
export LC_ALL=es_ES.utf8 
export LANG="$LC_ALL"
```

After that you can use:

```
print s.encode("utf-8")
```

Note: Also check that es_ES is within the available encodings with:

```
locale -a
```